# Angular/Protractor Test: After running first test, dropdown options no longer clickable

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, e2e-testing, gulp-protractor

Running a test where a dropdown list is selected from.  However, after running the first spec, the option tag can no longer be selected.  I've isolated each spec to make sure they are working.  This issue only occurs when tests are run in succession.

Here is the code I am using to select the dropdown options:

```
element.all(by.cssContainingText('option', keyword)).first().click();
```

This is the error that I am receiving after the second test runs:

```
Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.cssContainingText("option", "keyword")
```

HTML:

```
<select>
   <option>David</option>
   <option>Karen</option>
   <option>Linda</option>
   <option>Charlie</option>
```

Keyword used: David

It says there are 0 elements on the page which means it is not recognizing the option values.  Every test works when run alone, the drop down is able to be selected.  This error only occurs when run in succession.

Also I've added browser sleeps to check the console and to see if the dropdown is clickable.  There appears to be no errors and when using my mouse, the option tags appear and are also clickable.  Also added waits and sleeps to see if it just takes some time for the options to appear.  Seems to be an issue with protractor identifying the options.

Comment: Please add the HTML of your select object. also add what keyword was used.

Comment: Hi Paul, just added the html of select object, there not much to it though

Comment: Can you try inspecting the element when the dropdown list is not open? I am checking if the options are only visible after clicking the dropdown

Comment: yes I am able to inspect the element even if the drop down list is not open.  I've test for both when it is open and when closed and both are not working.  However, when running each test individually, the options are able to be selected when the drop down is either closed and selected so that should not be an issue.

Comment: is your application accessible outside your network?

Comment: nope not yet, do you think this might be the cause for the issue ?

Comment: I was asking so that I or others can check it ourselves. There might be some behavior differences.